# NTP service not taking into account its config file

Tags: linux, time, ntp

On Raspbian Linux 10, configuring NTP drives me crazy.

In `/etc/ntp.conf` there is this line:

```
logfile /tmp/ntp.log
```

However, the `systemctl start ntp` service doesn't print *anything* into this file.

When I run `ntpd` manually, it prints to this file.

Why ntp service is not taking into account this config file?

Note: this is a console-only system, no chrony, no timedatectl is active.

How can I make this service to behave as intended?

Comment: Have you checked the actual command line of the service? It may override the log location, typically to _stdout_ with Systemd.

Comment: actual command line is `/usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -u x:y` is this overriding anything?

Comment: If I run this manually (with sudo) I got my clock updated correctly AND it logs to the required file set in `/etc/ntp.conf`.

Comment: Perhaps there is a second `logfile` declaration in the config file. You may want to edit the question and post the systemd service file. Also post the output of `systemctl status ntp`.